# Can 形象 be used as a verb?

Tags: usage

In this definition “丑陋：难看。多形象人或事物的相貌、样子。”, 形象 seems to me functioning like a verb, but I can't find such a usage in MDBG, Wenlin, dict.baidu.com.

Do I get it wrong or does it indeed function like a verb?

Answer (score 2):

形象 is strictly a noun for 'image'

> *in this definition “丑陋：难看。多形象人或事物的相貌、样子。”*

Obviously, 形象 is a typo of 形容 (describe) here

The correct sentence is :

丑陋：难看。多**形容**人或事物的相貌、样子

丑陋：ugly. Mostly **describes** the appearance and looks of people or things

Answer (score 0):

No. 形象 is a noun, it is the external image/impression of a person seeing by others regarding the way he/she talks and acts, also the advocates and causes he/she stands for or promoting on.

- 他作人行事中規中矩, 給人一個良好的形象.
- 他給人的形象是正直誠實.
- 他的主張給他製造了良好的形象.
- 在工作上, 他的形象很差.

Similarly, 丑陋 is a noun. However, 丑化 is a  verb, as in 丑化一個人的形象.

Answer (score 0):

形象：n. Image(n)
Adj. vivid; e.g. 这个描述很形象。

The quote you gave is actually not very modernly correct. It’d be more acceptable to say “ 多形容人或事物的相貌”。

It might have been used as a verb in the past, but not nowadays.